# Are Lactaid tablets Chametz Gamur?

Tags: medicine, chametz-leaven

I have a veritable million little lactaid chewable tablets sitting around my house. I cannot find a single person who is clear on whether or not they're chametz Gamur, or even Kitniyot for that matter. If they're chametz Gamur, I have to get rid of them fully. I've heard that I shouldn't eat them- but no one is clear on whether they're kitniyot or chametz Gamur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual the answer is that it is a machlokes. Apparently, lactaid milk bought before Pesach is in the same category as Vitamin D enhanced milk bought before Pesach. However, the problem is with your situation, the pills. Aparently **non-chewable** lactaid pills may (or may not) be acceptable (though of course CYLOR)

[cRc Kosher 5776 Pesach Top Ten Questions](http://matzav.com/crc-kosher-5776-pesach-top-ten-questions/)

> Q: I am lactose intolerant. What are my options for Passover this
>   year?
>
> A: Lactaid non-chewable pills are acceptable for Passover.  Lactaid
>   milk is also acceptable but must be purchased before the holiday.

[Star-K 2016 list](http://www.star-k.org/articles/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/STAR-KProductDirectory_2016.pdf)

> **LACTAID**
>
> Caplets  may  contain  chometz  and  may  not  be  used  on  Pesach.
>
> Lactaid  Milk  may  be  used  on  Pesach if purchased BEFORE Pesach. 
>   This product is not Cholov Yisroel

.
[Lactose Intolerant - OU](https://oukosher.org/passover/guidelines/medicine-guidlines/lactose-intolerant/)

> Lactaid production is likely to involve chometz. This renders chewable
>   lactaid tablets problematic. Lactaid non-chewable tablets are more
>   complicated. Many rabbinical authorities permit non-chewable vitamins
>   and supplements without regard to their kashruth status. According to
>   such opinions, one may take these tablets just like any other
>   non-chewable pill.
>
> Other rabbinical authorities believe that vitamins and supplements are
>   akin to food even when swallowed. According to this opinion one may
>   take the lactaid tablet when wrapped in tissue paper. However, one who
>   is unable to do so may swallow the tablet without wrapping it, and
>   rely on the lenient authorities, since milk is such an important
>   health need. We suggest that you consult with your local rabbi as to
>   which of these opinions you should follow.
>
> We certify a number of lactose reduced products for Passover. Please
>   consult our Passover product search for more information.